# Retrofit unknown amount of numbered JSON objects

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am using retrofit in the Android app. I cannot figure out how to process JSON that comes in a format below. Retrofit puts data into an ArrayList automatically if data comes in an array, how do I put it in an ArrayList if it comes like this?

It is not known how many JSON objects (identified by a number) there are going to be.

What I need is an ArrayList (or any other data set) holding and object that consists of only what's inside the "value" i.e. **id, value, title**.

P.S. I know that the data in the JSON is redundant, however, I do not have access to the API and I have to work with what I have for now.

```
{
    "0":{
        "id":0,
        "value":{
            "id":2,
            "value":"Vehicle Battery Connection Removed",
            "title":"Vehicle Battery Connection Removed"
        },
        "title":{
            "id":2,
            "value":"Vehicle Battery Connection Removed",
            "title":"Vehicle Battery Connection Removed"
        }
    },
    "1":{
        "id":1,
        "value":{
            "id":4,
            "value":"SOS",
            "title":"SOS"
        },
        "title":{
            "id":4,
            "value":"SOS",
            "title":"SOS"
        }
    },
    "2":{
        "id":2,
        "value":{
            "id":8,
            "value":"GPS Signal not valid",
            "title":"GPS Signal not valid"
        },
        "title":{
            "id":8,
            "value":"GPS Signal not valid",
            "title":"GPS Signal not valid"
        }
    },
    "status":1
}
```

Here is the POJO for holding the data (id, title, value):

```
public class CustomEventByProtocol
{
    public int id;
    public String title, value;

    @Override
    public String toString() { return value; }
}
```

Here is the request:

```
@GET("/get_events_by_protocol")
void getEventsByProtocolForDropdown(@Query("user_api_hash") String user_api_hash, @Query("lang") String lang, @Query("type") int type, @Query("protocol") String protocol, Callback<CustomEventsByProtocol> cb);

class CustomEventsByProtocol
{
    public ArrayList<CustomEventByProtocol> list;
    // HOW TO POPULATE THiS LIST?
}
```

Comment: use a json to pojo converter online. Use gsonconverter with retrofit and ou should have your json converted to pojo's

Comment: Have you got the present JSON into objects?

Comment: Raghunandan - I have just tried it and it does not do what I need the online converter (I've tried several) treat JSON as static, and creates a POJO for each numbered JSON object, that is not what I want. I need some kind of iteration.

Coder - no